# Convert string to column name

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql, dynamic-sql

I'm trying to write a simple postgres function which looks more or less like that:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION USER_TOTALS(column_name varchar, in_t users) RETURNS float AS $$
  DECLARE
    sum float;
  BEGIN
    sum = (SELECT SUM($1) FROM jobs WHERE jobs.technician_id = in_t.id);
    RETURN sum;
  END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

And i need to use it like that:

```
SELECT users.*, USER_TOTALS('jobs.price', users.*) AS total_price_value FROM users;
```

Hovewer, that's obviously not working cause `SUM()` function expects to get a column name but my code passes a varchar to it, so the error says:

```
Function sum(character varying) does not exist
```

The question is - can i somehow cast a varchar variable to column name var type? I've been googling for this thing for about 2 hours now and i have no idea how can i make that happen.

Comment: Look up PL/PgSQL "EXECUTE" and "dynamic SQL"; see many related answers here.

Comment: Well, to be honest, all the examples uses various variable types and as long as my column name is passed as a varchar, i'm not able to use it in any way. Probably i need to change it's type to 'column_name' or cast it but the main problem is i have no idea if there is such var type and i'm not able to find anything about that topic on the internet. Thanks for your suggestion but i'm affraid i'm not able to use it :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A recommended form:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION USER_TOTALS(column_name varchar, in_t users) 
RETURNS float AS $$
DECLARE 
  sum float;
BEGIN
  EXECUTE format('SELECT SUM(%I) FROM jobs WHERE jobs.technician_id=$1', column_name)
    INTO sum
    USING in_t;
  RETURN sum;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION USER_TOTALS(column_name varchar, in_t users) RETURNS float AS $$
DECLARE 
    sum float;
BEGIN
    EXECUTE 'SELECT SUM('||column_name||') FROM jobs WHERE jobs.technician_id='||in_t INTO sum;
    RETURN sum;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Comment: You can't use `USING` to substitute identifiers. Use `format` and the `%I` format-specifier.

Comment: This is a SQL injection vulnerable! You should to escape all string values.